# LWC with Leaflet JS >> Mouseover not working as expected in L.geoJson

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, leaflet.js

I'm working with Leaflet.JS in a Lightning Community to render a world map. So far everything seems to be working right, but something that I'd like to do is to have the name of the country that the user mouses over come up in a popup. I've been using the onEachFeature section to add functionality to the countries (i.e. on click) and tried doing the same thing with a mouseover event to show the popup. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to happen on mouse over, but it does occur once I click on the country.

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import leaflet from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/leaflet';
import {loadScript, loadStyle} from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import getJSONFromResource from '@salesforce/apex/WorldMapController.getJSON';

export default class WorldMap extends LightningElement {
    librariesInitialised = false;
    mapApplied = false;
    countryMapKey = {};
    selectedCountries = [];
    geoJSON;

    renderedCallback(){
        if(this.librariesInitialised) {
            return;
        }
        this.librariesInitialised = true;

        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, leaflet + '/leaflet.js'),
            loadStyle(this, leaflet + '/leaflet.css')
        ])
            .then(() => {
                this.getJSON();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('An error occurred while loading scripts');
            })
    }

    getJSON() {
        getJSONFromResource()
            .then(result => {
                this.geoJSON = JSON.parse(result);
                this.setupMap();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('An error occurred while getting JSON');
            })
    }

    setupMap() {
        const mapRoot = this.template.querySelector(".map-root");
        this.map = L.map(mapRoot).setView([0, 0], 0);
        this.mapSetter();
    }

    mapSetter() {
        L.geoJSON(this.geoJSON, {
            clickable: true,
            style: (item) => {
                return {
                    fillColor: '#fff',
                    fillOpacity:1,
                    fill:true,
                    color:'#eeeeff',
                    weight:1
                }
            },
            onEachFeature: (feature, layer) => {
                this.countryMapKey[layer.feature.properties.name] = feature;
                let name = feature.properties.name;
                if(this.selectedCountries.includes(feature.properties.name)){
                    layer.setStyle({
                        fillColor: ctxFillColor()
                    });
                }

                function ctxFillColor() {
                    return '#FFFF00';
                }

                layer.on('click',
                    () => {
                        if(this.selectedCountries.indexOf(layer.feature.properties.name) == -1) {
                            this.selectedCountries.push(layer.feature.properties.name);
                            layer.setStyle({
                                fillColor: ctxFillColor()
                            });
                        } else {
                            this.selectedCountries.splice(this.selectedCountries.indexOf(layer.feature.properties.name));
                            layer.setStyle({
                                fillColor: '#fff'
                            });
                        }
                });

                layer.on('mouseover', function(){
                    layer.bindPopup(layer.feature.properties.name);
                });
                layer.on('mouseout', function(){
                    layer.closePopup();
                });

            }
        }).addTo(this.map);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can get the popup to show up on mouse over without having to click on the country first? Or is this just a limitation I'll have to work with?

Thanks in advance for any help with this.